# Change Stereotypes of multiple Packages selected in Project Browser at once - Enterprise Architect

Tags: scripting, package, enterprise-architect, stereotype

as explained in the title: I want to change the **Steretypes** of multiple **Packages** at once, which are **selected** in the **Project Browser**. I want to do this with the built-in scripting function.

I tried to stick to the "VBScript Project Browser Multi Selection Example" but it seems impossible to change the Stereotypes of multiple packages.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Packages and Elements are treated differently in the Project Browser, so **Repository.GetTreeSelectedElements()** will return an empty collection if a Package is selected. What EA needs is a **Repository.GetTreeSelectedPackages()** method, but until then I'm afraid you're out of luck.

Comment: Thanks for the Response! I hope this feater will be added in the future :/